# Select-Option and input-date isn't set by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I have a Problem with setting the data from the database to my select and to my input (date and text allready tried) in the HTML file. Is there anything missing or what's wrong?

Here are my imports:

```
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.de.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-filter.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="js/collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Here the html sector:

```
<table class="table mb-1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"> </th>
                        <th scope="col"> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Beobachten</th>
                        <td>
                            <select id="selectTracking" ng-model="tracking" class="wdselect">
                                <option ng-value="0">Nein</option>
                                <option ng-value="1">Ja</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Ansprache</th>
                        <td>
                            <select id="selectRequest" ng-model="request" class="wdselect">
                                <option ng-value="0">Nein</option>
                                <option ng-value="1">Ja</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Response</th>
                        <td>
                            <select id="selectResponse" ng-model="response" class="wdselect">
                                <option ng-value="0">Nein</option>
                                <option ng-value="1">Ja</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-if="response == 1">
                        <th scope="row"> </th>
                        <td>
                            <select id="selectResponseValue" ng-model="responseVal" class="wdselect" onchange="setResponseVal(this.value)">
                                <option ng-value="0">Negativ</option>
                                <option ng-value="1">Positiv</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="input-group date">
                <div class="input-group-addon alert-info">Research</div>
                <input type='text' id="research" class="form-control" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="oi oi-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

[Browser shows the select-items correct with the id as value and name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV7Pj.png)

In my JavaScript, I set the value with the value which I get from my NodeJS

```
    /**
     * get Candidate-data to fill into Form for updating selected Team
     */
    $http.post('candidate/info', { candidateid: $routeParams.candidateid }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.candidate = response.data.data.candidate;
        $scope.sources = response.data.data.sources;
        $scope.teams = response.data.data.teams;
        $scope.citys = response.data.data.citys;
        $scope.sourcer = response.data.data.sourcer;

        $scope.iserrmessage = !response.data.sucess;
        $scope.message = response.data.message;

        $scope.tracking;
        $scope.request;
        $scope.response;
        $scope.responseVal;

        $scope.research = toLocalDate($scope.candidate.research);

        var research = $('#research');

        research.datetimepicker();
        research.data('DateTimePicker').date($scope.research);
        research.on('dp.change', function (e) {
            $scope.candidate.research = e.date;
        });


        var selectTracking = $('#selectTracking');
        selectTracking.select2();

        var selectRequest = $('#selectRequest');
        selectRequest.select2();

        var selectResponse = $('#selectResponse');
        selectResponse.select2();

        selectTracking.val($scope.candidate.tracking);
        selectTracking.trigger("change");
        selectTracking.on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var id = selectTracking.val();
            $scope.tracking = id;
        });

        selectRequest.val($scope.candidate.request);
        selectRequest.trigger("change");
        selectRequest.on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var id = selectRequest.val();
            $scope.request = id;
        });

        selectResponse.val($scope.candidate.response);
        selectResponse.trigger("change");
        selectResponse.on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var id = selectResponse.val();
            $scope.response = id;
        });

    });//end candidate/info
```

The Code in my NodeJS:

```
        /**
         * Kandidat Infos anzeigen - candidateDetail
         */
        app.post('/candidate/info', function (req, res) {
            if (req.session.userid) {
                var parameter = [req.body.candidateid];
                var candidatequery = "SELECT candidate.id, candidate.firstname as firstname," +
                    "CASE WHEN candidate.lastname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE candidate.lastname END AS lastname," +
                    "sources.name as source, candidate.source_id as source_id, candidate.source_text, candidate.eR," +
                    "CASE WHEN candidate.intern = '0000-00-00' THEN '-' ELSE candidate.intern END AS intern," +
                    "CASE WHEN candidate.extern = '0000-00-00' THEN '-' ELSE candidate.extern END AS extern," +
                    "CASE WHEN candidate.hire = '0000-00-00' THEN '-' ELSE candidate.hire END AS hire," +
                    "CASE WHEN candidate.telnotice = '0000-00-00' THEN '-' ELSE candidate.telnotice END AS telnotice," +
                    "CASE WHEN candidate.response_value = null THEN '-' ELSE candidate.response_value END AS response_value," +
                    "candidate.tracking, candidate.request, candidate.response," +
                    "city_group.city, team.name as teamname, candidate.research, candidate.date, users.firstname as sourcerName, candidate.sourcer " +
                    "FROM candidate LEFT JOIN sources ON candidate.source_id = sources.id " +
                    "LEFT JOIN team ON team.id = candidate.team_id " +
                    "LEFT JOIN city_group ON team.city_group = city_group.id " +
                    "LEFT JOIN users ON candidate.sourcer = users.id " +
                    "WHERE candidate.id = ?";

                var sourcequery = "SELECT id, name FROM sources WHERE active=1";
                var teamquery = "SELECT team.id, team.name, team.city_group, city_group.city FROM team " +
                    "LEFT JOIN city_group ON team.city_group = city_group.id " +
                    " WHERE team.active=1";
                var cityquery = "SELECT id, city FROM city_group";
                var userquery = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE active=1";

                    db.query(candidatequery, parameter, function (err, rows, fields) {
                        if (err) throw err;

                        if (rows.length == 0) {
                            sendResponse(res, false, "Kandidat nicht gefunden!");
                        } else {
                            db.query(sourcequery, function (sourceerr, sourcerows, sourcefields) {
                                if (sourceerr) throw sourceerr;

                                db.query(teamquery, function (teamerr, teamrows, teamfields) {
                                    if (teamerr) throw teamerr;

                                    db.query(cityquery, function (cityerr, cityrows, cityfields) {
                                        if (cityerr) throw cityerr;

                                        db.query(userquery, function (usererr, userrows, userfields) {
                                            if (usererr) throw usererr;

                                            var result = {
                                                candidate: rows[0],
                                                sources: sourcerows,
                                                teams: teamrows,
                                                citys: cityrows,
                                                sourcer: userrows
                                            };

                                            sendResponse(res, true, "", result); 

                                        });//end userquery
                                    });//end cityquery
                                });//end teamquery
                            });//end sourcequery  
                        }//end Kandidat gefunden
                    });//end db.query(candidatequery)

            } else {
                sendResponse(res, false, "Kein Benutzer eingeloggt!");
            }
        }); //end candidate/info
```

I work with Google Chrome, in the Developer View I can see that the values are sent to the Browser (as you can see in the Image below), but the select doesn't show the option.

[Developer-View in the Browser (all data is received - but not displayed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Y5S.png)

I have the same Problem with my input date Fields as well.
I have the data from the database but I can't set it to the input-fields. There are no error-Messages, it just doesn't work.

Comment: there will be datatype mismatch between `sourceSelect` and `s.id`. Try by assigning string value to `sourceSelect`.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible because your example is incomplete. Please post a minimal working code with your angular controller/directive.

Comment: i have uploaded the relevant code-parts. i hope you can help me with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your html code within a form like below

```html
  <form ng-submit="submitFunction()">
    <div class="input-group mb-1">
      <div class="input-group-addon alert-info">Source</div>
         <select class="custom-select wdselect" id="selectSource"
          ng-model="sourceSelect"
          ng-change="showSourceValue(sourceSelect)">
           <option ng-repeat="s in sources" ng-value="{{s.id}}">
              {{s.name}}
           </option>
         </select>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: I can read all the data in my html where i create a new 'candidate' but as soon as i want to edit a candidate (selected by id) i cannot prefill the form-fields with the data from the database...

Answer (score -1):

SO, You cant Set the selected data which is retrieved from Database ryt?
Try this way.

```
$scope.sourceSelect={
"name":ResopnseObj.source,
"id":ResponseObj.id
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing over here?